# how to get the validators vec in runtime in substrate

Tags: rust, blockchain, substrate

I'm facing an issue to get the validators in runtime, basically want to distribute the fee to validators. but giving an error at validators fetching.

```
   pub struct DealWithFees<R>(sp_std::marker::PhantomData<R>);
impl<R> OnUnbalanced<NegativeImbalance<R>> for DealWithFees<R>
where
    R: pallet_balances::Config + pallet_authorship::Config,
{
    fn on_unbalanceds<B>(mut fees_then_tips: impl Iterator<Item = NegativeImbalance<R>>) {
        if let Some(fees) = fees_then_tips.next() {
            // for fees, 80% to treasury, 20% to author
            let mut split = fees.ration(80, 20);
            if let Some(tips) = fees_then_tips.next() {
                // for tips, if any, 100% to author
                tips.merge_into(&mut split.1);
            }
            // <Treasury<R> as OnUnbalanced<_>>::on_unbalanced(split.0);
            <ToAuthor<R> as OnUnbalanced<_>>::on_unbalanced(split.1);

            let mut validators = session::Module::<T>::validators();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @jmb Sure, will remember next time

Comment: You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73245181/edit) the question to replace the image with a text version of the error.